# Insertion into map not sorted properly

Tags: c++, dictionary

I am confused why the records are not sorted in the map.

```
 class point{
 public:    string s1,s2;
 public:        point(string string1, string string2){
            s1=string1;s2=string2;
    }

 };

 bool operator<(const point &p1, const point &p2)
 {
    cout<<"p1.s1.compare(p2.s1)="<<p1.s1.compare(p2.s1)<<" p1.s1="<<p1.s1<<"  p2.s1="<<p2.s1<<endl;
    return p1.s1.compare(p2.s1);
 }
 int main(int argc, char *argv[])
 {
    std::map<point,int>m1;
    point p1("hello","hi");
    m1.insert(std::make_pair(p1,1));
    point p2("abc","kbd");
    m1.insert(std::make_pair(p2,2));
    point p3("hell","hi");
    m1.insert(std::make_pair(p3,3));

    std::map<point,int>::iterator it=m1.begin();
    while(it!=m1.end())
    {
        cout<<"m1.first="<<it->first.s1<<"  m1.first.s2="<<it->first.s2<<"  m1.second="<<it->second<<endl;
        it++;
    }
    return 0;
 }
```

The output is

```
m1.first=hell  m1.first.s2=hi  m1.second=3
m1.first=abc  m1.first.s2=kbd  m1.second=2
m1.first=hello  m1.first.s2=hi  m1.second=1
```

But the output expected was

```
m1.first=abc  m1.first.s2=kbd  m1.second=2
m1.first=hell  m1.first.s2=hi  m1.second=3
m1.first=hello  m1.first.s2=hi  m1.second=1
```

Could anyone please clarify, is this the way insertion works in RB tree, or some other problem exists.

Comment: Why do you expect to get that output? What should it sort on and why?

Comment: The compare needs to be sent to the map constructor and it needs to be a binary predicate that returns a true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `operator<` function needs to return `true` if the LHS is supposed to be less than the RHS. `std::string::compare()` does not return such a value. It returns a negative value, zero, or a positive value.

What you need to do is use:

```
return (p1.s1.compare(p2.s1) < 0 );
```

or use the already defined `operator<` for strings.

```
return (p1.s1 < p2.s1);
```

Answer (score 0):

I thought string::compare() returns an int value.  At best this would be implicitly converted to a bool. You might be messing up your less operator by not handling this correctly